# How do I generate a SunEC Key?

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, java-security

I am trying to generate a key using the EC algorithm. I tried to do it like this...

`keytool -genkeypair -keystore src/test/resources/org/jgleason/auth/client-ec.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass changeit -alias ec-client -keyalg EC -providername SunEC -dname "CN=ec-client"`

But when I run I get

`keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS12 not found`

How do I generate a key for this algorithm type?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? NB The word is ‘algorithm’. It derives from someone’s name.

Comment: I am using 17 not sure what NB means?

Comment: [Nota bene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene). It is often used to indicate another point somebody is making besides the main point (which would be asking for the Java version in this case). Wondering what you will get if you leave `-providername SunEC` out of the call?

Comment: I am trying to test provider name so I would rather avoid that. We already have tests for the algo being different. Did I spell algorithm wrong some where or something? Or are you just referring to the title? Feel free to edit it and I will accept the changes